# Understanding fork() in for loop and usage of exit()

Tags: c, process, fork

Hey I have a question regarding `fork()` and how it behaves in a `for` loop.

So following is asked from me:

Create a Parent Process that creates 10 child Processes each of them printing the actual `i` value in the for loop. Is this code correct?

```
int i;

for(i=0;i < 10;i++){
  if(fork()==0){
     print(i);
  }
  exit(0);
}
```

My understanding is that this snippet of code creates on every loop iteration a parent and a child, where the parent terminates directly and the child prints `i`;

So to have only one parent and 10 children each of them printing `i`, I should wrap the `exit(0)` like this:

```
int i;
int p;

for(i=0;i < 10;i++){
  if((p=fork())==0){
     print(i);
  }
  if(p > 0){
  exit(0);
  }
}
```

Can someone confirm or this if its right, or help me to get a better understanding if its wrong.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fork()` call creates not a pair of new processes (parent, child), but leaves original process (parent) and creates **one** another process (child), so it "returns twice".

In your first snippet you really have only one parent. The only problem, it finishes on the very first iteration. :)

Look: `i = 0`, now we have only parent process (call it `P`).
`P` enters `fork()` and leaves it twice: in `P` (returning the PID of the child) and in the newly created child `C0` (returning 0). Then, according to `if` statement, `C0` prints `0`, `P` does nothing. Then execution paths converges, and both `P` and `C0` exit. Now we have no our processes at all.

Your second snippet's loop body can be rewritten as follows:

```
p = fork();
if (p == 0) {
    print(i);
}
if (p > 0) {
    exit(0);
}
```

Supposing `fork()` will not return negative number (error), these two `if` bodies are in fact just like `then`-`else` branches. They cause child process to print its number and *old* parent process to exit, so you got a waterfall of processes replacing one another in a sequence (most of them act exactly once as a child and then as parent).

You just need to rewrite it as such:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    p = fork();
    if (p == 0) {
        print(i);
        exit(0);
    }
    // In fact, you should place waitpid(...) somewhere here,
    // otherwise the child will become a so called zombie process 
    // after its  termination.
    // Only after parent termination they all will be
    // finally recycled by init (PID 1) generally using up your system's 
    // resources for indefinite time
}
```

Now you have `P` that creates `C0`. `C0` prints its number and immediately exits, while `P` just continues to the next loop iteration creating `C1` that just like `C0` prints its number and exits and so on. AFAIK it is what initially requested.

Please note that in real life you will have to somehow process the `-1` return value that indicate some error in the `fork()` call (so in reality, in the second snippet rewritten by me there is a possibility that neither `if` statement will execute), I have omitted them for simplicity.

Comment: Please note that in this solution it is **your shell** that creates the parent process. And this parent creates 10 children as requested. I don't know whether it is exactly what you need. Hope it is :)